# Django Error - settings.DATABASES is improperly configured

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, devstack

I have a problem with Django 1.6.2. Whenever I run stack.sh (devstack), I get the below error.

```
2014-04-22 17:24:36 + cd /opt/stack/horizon
2014-04-22 17:24:36 + python manage.py syncdb --noinput
2014-04-22 17:24:36 Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-04-22 17:24:36   File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
2014-04-22 17:24:36     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
2014-04-22 17:24:36   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
2014-04-22 17:24:36     utility.execute()
2014-04-22 17:24:36   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
2014-04-22 17:24:36     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
2014-04-22 17:24:36   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
2014-04-22 17:24:36     self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
2014-04-22 17:24:36   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
2014-04-22 17:24:36     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
2014-04-22 17:24:36   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
2014-04-22 17:24:36     return self.handle_noargs(**options)
2014-04-22 17:24:36   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
2014-04-22 17:24:36     cursor = connection.cursor()
2014-04-22 17:24:36   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 157, in cursor
2014-04-22 17:24:36     cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
2014-04-22 17:24:36   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 15, in complain
2014-04-22 17:24:36     raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
2014-04-22 17:24:36 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

> $ DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=openstack_dashboard.settings ./manage.py
>   runserver Validating models... 0 errors found April 22, 2014 -
>   21:37:57 Django version 1.6.2, using settings
>   'openstack_dashboard.settings' Starting development server at
>   127.0.0.1:8000 Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me with that, considering that I am new to devstack.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you add your DATABASES setting in settings.py? You haven't specified your engine correctly.

Comment: Can you show how you configured `settings.DATABASES`? You probably forgot or misspelled the name of the DB engine (i.e mysql or sqlite etc)

Comment: I am using sqlite3DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'}}

Comment: $ DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=openstack_dashboard.settings ./manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
April 22, 2014 - 21:37:57
Django version 1.6.2, using settings 'openstack_dashboard.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Comment: Please include these comments as part of your original post (edit them in), it's unreadable like this. Also, please show us as much relevant information as possible, it might be a very small mistake, but even if it isn't - if we can't reproduce it it would be hard to trace

Comment: Have you made any changes to the Horizon code? An ImproperlyConfigured  exception for settings.DATABASES can be a telltale of a circular import with your settings file (just a telltale - not certain proof) but I'm guessing there wouldn't be a circular reference in the vanilla Horizon code.

Comment: I didn't touch the horizon code.

Answer (score 0):

**Django version 1.6.2** it cause the problem some classes in old version of django depricated so you should upgrade the new version just enter that : `pip install django --upgrade` then it works fine